# What's the ERROR here in this code...? PHP

Tags: php

Here is a random password generator code. I'm getting this error when I tried running it.

I also tried running this code on some of the online PHP executers.

ERROR:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function split() in /home/cg/root/1626987/main.php:26
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /home/cg/root/1626987/main.php(44): randomPass(10, 1, 'lower_case,uppe...')
>       #1 {main}
>         thrown in /home/cg/root/1626987/main.php on line 26

Please help me with the following code

```
<?php

    function randomPass($length,$count, $characters) {

        $symbols = array();
        $passwords = array();
        $used_symbols = '';
        $pass = '';

        $symbols["lower_case"] = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        $symbols["upper_case"] = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $symbols["numbers"] = '1234567890';
        $symbols["special_symbols"] = '!?~@#-_+<>[]{}';

        $characters = split(",",$characters); 
        foreach ($characters as $key=>$value) {
            $used_symbols .= $symbols[$value]; 
        }
        $symbols_length = strlen($used_symbols) - 1; 

        for ($p = 0; $p < $count; $p++) {
            $pass = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $n = rand(0, $symbols_length); 
                $pass .= $used_symbols[$n]; 
            }
            $passwords[] = $pass;
        }

        return $passwords;
    }

    $my_passwords = randomPass(10,1,"lower_case,upper_case,numbers,special_symbols");

    print_r($my_passwords);

    ?>
```

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: @Saurabh MeanMachine, you should read it once http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Comment: `split() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual on `split()` https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php states:

> **Warning**
>
> This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.
>
> Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [preg_split()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)
> - [explode()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
> - [str_split()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Side note, as per the **Notes**:

> **Tip** split() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. [preg_split()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is the suggested alternative to this function. If you don't require the power of regular expressions, it is faster to use [explode()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), which doesn't incur the overhead of the regular expression engine.

Comment: Their PHP version is obviously outdated.

Comment: and was most likely written on and for a version of php prior to 5.3, most likely 5.2 or even older than that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `explode()` instead of `split()`

```
 $characters = explode(",",$characters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Warning
This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

Alternatives to this function include:

```
preg_split()
explode()
str_split()
```